# How rebase works in Git

Tags: java, git, rebase

I am stuck doing some rebase with GitLab and now bit confused how really rebase is working. 
So initially I created one feature branch (Test1) from develop branch. 
This feature branch has 100's files that have been changed and 93 commits. Meanwhile someone also cut the branch from develop and made changes in 5 files and then merged this into develop branch.

Now  I want to rebase my feature branch (Test1) with develop to get the latest state of develop branch. 
Ideally there should be only 5 file conflict that have been edited in different branch.

but I don't know why there are plenty of file is coming during rebase and it looks all these files are modified in my branch (Test1).
One point, I modified few files multiple times and committed as well in branch (Test1), but I think this should not cause any problem.

Could someone help me on this to understand this rebase flow.

Answer (score 0):

First, got to `develop` branch and take the latest pull with the following commands,

```
git checkout develop
```

```
git pull origin develop
```

Now, navigate back to your branch `Test1` and try rebasing the develop branch by the following commands,

```
git checkout Test1
```

```
git rebase develop
```

Now try resolving the conflicts if any from the editor like VScode,
After resolving the conflicts add the changes and continue the rebase process till the command line shows that `no rebase in progress`.

```
Resolve Conflicts through Editor
```

```
git add .
```

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. But not sure from where 93 commits is coming. Ideally there are only 5 files that have been changed till I cut the feature branch. So it should show me 5 conflict. but show bunch of files. Its seems in feature branch Test1, there are files that have been modified twice or maybe more that that and git showing conflict between those commit in same feature Test1 branch.